# Bind object into variable Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Is there any possibility to bind Objects into Variable in Symfony 5 using Attributes?

For example, I have class:

```php
class Users 
{
    private $servers; 
}
```

I has property $servers. I want to bind some object to this class using Attributes with some functionality and validation.

Comment: You might be asking about [property injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#property-injection).  Not sure what `functionality and validation` means in this context.  Constructor and setter injection are generally preferred over property injection.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it if you inject it in your constructor like this

`services.yaml`

```
services:
  Users:
    arguments:
       $servers: <your value>
```

And in your Users class

```
class Users 
{
    private $servers; 

    public function __construct( $servers) 
    {
       $this->servers = $servers
     }
}
```